# чпу только в определенном каталоге

Tags: .htaccess

Приветствую всех вошедших

Представьте себе такое

```
http://какойтосайт.ru/ - тут лежит index.php, и как обычно загружает разный контент в зависимости от get строки
http://какойтосайт.ru/adminka/index.php - админка. Работает аналогично сайту
http://какойтосайт.ru/test/index.php - файл на котором тестирую
```

Подскажите, как в htaccess написать, что бы можно было использовать ЧПУ, в тестовой категории? Охота, что бы на сайте все работало без них, и в админке тоже.

p.s. Сейчас только учу чпу, если для вопроса надо, то в тестовой категории сейчас такие ссылки

```
index.php?a=...&b=...&c=...&d=...
index.php?a=...&b=...&c=...
index.php?a=...&b=...
index.php?a=...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Напишите это:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^test/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /test/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```